# Drawing a line between 2 points in line chart using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can we able draw line between 2 points at a specific category?

[image: Draw line similar to the red line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SVGRenderer` class object to render rect with some attributes. All what you need to do is to get the specific point pixel value, what you can achieve by `Axis.toPixels` method, and then just render the `rect` element basing on the data you've got. Here is the code:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            events: {
        load() {
            var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
            yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
            pointX = 5,
            pointY = 125000,
            secondPointY = 50000,
            width = 4,
            height = yAxis.toPixels(secondPointY) - yAxis.toPixels(pointY);

            this.renderer.rect(
            xAxis.toPixels(pointX) - (width / 2),
            yAxis.toPixels(pointY),
            width,
            height
          ).attr({
            fill: 'red'
          }).add()
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }]
});
```

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/h12q5x0d/

Answer (score 0):

Plot lines can be created on the x-axis. It can also be created on both axes:

```
xAxis: {
  plotLines: [{
    color: 'red', // Color value
    dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
    value: 3, // Value of where the line will appear
    width: 2 // Width of the line    
  }]
},
```

Reference: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Comment: Just to piggyback there is also the zoneAxis property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line